# Private constructor in class with static methods java

Tags: java, arraylist, static-methods, private-constructor

I'm trying to create a class that sorts an array list in descending order of marks. As all my methods are static, I want to write a constructor to prevent class instantiation but am not sure how to go about doing it. I read that a private constructor can be used but unsure how to go about coding it.

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ProcessDegreeMark{

public static ArrayList<Finalist> finalistsInList(String s) throws Exception{
    ArrayList<Finalist> finalists = new ArrayList<Finalist>();
    String id;
    double mark;
    Scanner in = null;
    try
    {
        in = new Scanner(new FileReader(s));
        try
        {
            while(in.hasNextLine())
            {
                id =in.nextLine();
                mark = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
                finalists.add(new Finalist(id,mark));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            in.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(s+" not found");
    }
    return finalists;
 }


public static void displayFinalists(ArrayList<Finalist> finalists){
  for (int i = 0; i < finalists.size(); i++)
  {
       System.out.println(finalists.get(i));
  }
}


public static void findFinalistID(ArrayList<Finalist> a, String s){
    int count =0;
    for (int i=1;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if (((a.get(i))).getId().equals(s))
        {
            System.out.println(a.get(i));
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
    {
        System.out.println("No candidate found with ID number "+s);
    }
}

public static void findFinalistClass(ArrayList<Finalist> a, String s){
    int count =0;
    for (int i=1;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if (((a.get(i))).getdegreeClass().equals(s))
        {
            System.out.println(a.get(i));
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
    {
        System.out.println("No candidate found with degree class "+s);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Finalist> sortDegreeMark(ArrayList<Finalist> a){
    ArrayList<Finalist> sortedFinalists = new ArrayList<Finalist>();
    sortedFinalists.addAll(a);
    Collections.sort(sortedFinalists, new FinalistComparator());
    return sortedFinalists;


}

public static void finalistsToFile2(ArrayList<Finalist> finalists, String s) {
    PrintStream out = null;
    try
    {
        out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(s));
        try
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < finalists.size(); i++)
            {
                out.println(finalists.get(i));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void findAndSaveFinalistClass(ArrayList<Finalist> a, String s){
    ArrayList<Finalist> searchFinalists = new ArrayList<Finalist>();
    int count =0;
    for (int i=1;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if (((a.get(i))).getdegreeClass().equals(s))
        {
            System.out.println(a.get(i));
            searchFinalists.add(a.get(i));
            finalistsToFile2(searchFinalists,"testSorted.txt");
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
    {
        System.out.println("No candidate found with degree class "+s);
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
 System.out.println("/****************************************************/");
         System.out.println("/*******finalistsInList with invalid file name*******/");
         System.out.println();
         ArrayList<Finalist> testList = finalistsInList("file***.txt");
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("/****************************************************/");
         System.out.println("/********finalistsInList with valid file name********/");
         System.out.println("/********display to check arraylist populated********/");
         System.out.println();
         ArrayList<Finalist> finalists = finalistsInList("finalMark.txt");
         displayFinalists(finalists);
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("/****************************************************/");
         System.out.println("/*testing findFinalistID with valid and invalid data*/");
         System.out.println();
         findFinalistID(finalists, "75021");  
         findFinalistID(finalists, "21050");
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("/****************************************************/");
         System.out.println("/*test findFinalistClass with valid and invalid data*/");
         System.out.println();
         findFinalistClass(finalists, "FIRST"); 
         findFinalistClass(finalists, "THIRD"); 
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("/****************************************************/");
         System.out.println("/*****run sortedFinalists then test with display*****/");
         System.out.println();
         ArrayList<Finalist> sortedFinalists = sortDegreeMark(finalists);
         displayFinalists(sortedFinalists);
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("/****************************************************/");
         System.out.println("/*****test finalistsToFile2 with sorted arraylist*****/");
         System.out.println("/**************check file testSorted.txt**************/");
         System.out.println();
         finalistsToFile2(sortedFinalists, "testSorted.txt"); //save the sorted arraylist to a new file, check by opening file
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("/****************************************************/");
         System.out.println("/*test findAndSaveFinalistClass with valid and invalid data*/");
         System.out.println();
         findAndSaveFinalistClass(finalists, "FIRST"); //test method finds
         findAndSaveFinalistClass(finalists, "THRID"); //check appropriate error message when nothing found, open new text file
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("/*********************THE END************************/");
     }
}
```

Comment: Look at the techniques for making a singleton

Comment: I can not see why you want to do this

Comment: @ScaryWombat correct me if I'm wrong but I understand that since the ProcessDegreeMark class has only static methods, it would not be appropriate to make an instance of it and hence a constructor is useful in preventing class instantiation?

Comment: Yes, but as you are using purely static data it would not matter whether you had a constructor or not.  I was thinking more the other way as in *why have all methods being static* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods belong to the class. I don't really understand why are you worrying about having/not having class instantiation. whether they create one instance or multiple instance the callers will have the same copy of static method.Having said that, You can still limit instantation outside the class by adding a default private constructor  like below

```
private ProcessDegreeMark(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add private modifier before constructor.

```
public class ProcessDegreeMark{
    private ProcessDegreeMark(){}
}
```